# modelBuilder add somente uma variavel com varchar diferente

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Em meu sistema, eu tenho um pequeno código que adiciona varchar para todas as variáveis adicionadas no banco

```
modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
.Configure(p => p.HasMaxLength(150));
```

só que preciso que apenas uma variavel seja varchar(1000) alguem poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: Isso é EntityFramework?

Comment: Configura essa tal variável na linha debaixo.

Comment: @JulioBorges Sim é Entity

Comment: @jbueno pode me dar um Exemplo ?

Comment: @LeonardoMacedo Eu vou procurar algo aqui. Fiquei de criar uma resposta ontem, mas me perdi no meio de tantas abas abertas.

Comment: @jbueno Tudo bem, fico aguardando sua resposta, e muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver a minha duvida,
vou estar postando aqui a baixo o código

```
public EventosAdversosConfig()
{
    Property(x => x.diaea1)
        .HasColumnType("varchar")
        .HasMaxLength(1000)
        .IsOptional();
}
```